# Generate different messages in a webpage according to some constraints like name of the person. HTML, JavaScript, PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have few messages stored in database which have message ids like: msg34,msg53,msg12,etc. With each id is associated persons name like "Dan", "Nick",etc.

So when I enter a name, it should display all these messages one by one, eg: a new message associated with that person is displayed on my webpage every 1 min, say.

This is what I have so far in my php file which obviously just displays a single message that I fetch from the database. How do I ensure that I can display messages according to the "name" and this displays a new message associated with the "name" every 1 minute. eg: "name" = "Dan" msgid = msg23, msg24,msg30,msg82. So, after every one minute next message is displayed.

How should I go about achieving this using html/javascript/php?

```
   <script>
      $(function(){
          $("#includedContent").load("/dir1/dir2/msg22.html");
      });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <?php
        $name = "";
        if (isset($_GET["personsName"])){ 
              $name = $_GET["personsName"];
         }
   ?>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="includedContent"><div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you made any database connection to get the respective msgs?

Comment: Yes, I have made database connection to get the message. I would probably need to write a query something like---> $messages= "SELECT message FROM   MessagesList WHERE person = '$name'";     
$messagesData = mysql_fetch_assoc($messages);

Comment: Thats right, if you are trying to load content in `#includedContent` div every 1 min, then better rename the page msg22.html to msg22.php, you can execute your DB queries on that page and display the result here every 1 minute using the JS setInterval method.

Comment: How do I iterate through these messages which are in .html format?

Comment: Oh! In the post you mentioned msgs are in database, anyway, in this case you can fetch messages from database directly on the same page, I can help you with the code if you add some code in your post, cannot write whole code for you. Can you add at least the basic database part of code (Select queries and all?)

Comment: Refer [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) and add the basic code to display your Select query result, I can help you with the rest then.

Comment: @Echoes: The message ids are stored in Database and using these messages ids we generate message.html file which is located at /dir1/dir2/msg35.html     <script>
      $(function(){
          $("#includedContent").load("/dir1/dir2/msg22.html");
      });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <?php
        $name = "";
        if (isset($_GET["personsName"])){ 
              $name = $_GET["personsName"];
         }
   ?>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="includedContent"><div>
</body>

Comment: That's just msg22, where are other messages? If in the database, then where are you fetching them?

Comment: $messages= "SELECT message FROM MessagesList WHERE person = '$name'"; $messagesData = mysql_fetch_assoc($messages);     so msg22 is one of the rows in $messagesData. There would be more like msg33,msg34, and so on.  This function should then be able to display all the messages like :   $(function(){
          $("#includedContent").load("/dir1/dir2/messagesData[0].html");
      });

Comment: You cannot load $messagesData the way you have mentioned in your comment. I know there would be more like msg22, what I wanted to see was your loop where you iterate through all the rows of `$messagesData` so that I could just provide you clear solution with code. Without seeing the code, how and what logic you are following I can only [refer you to this function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), you can put your JS script between setInterval method to keep calling it at some interval.

Comment: Also, you are loading the msg before you access the name, I wonder how you are loading msg without any name.